# Emails are not sending

Tags: magento2, email, cron

Recently I setup Magento. I tried signing up as an user and buying a product, however, I see no emails are coming through to the customer when the order gets processed or when a user tries to reset a password. I have cron setup, however, no idea why emails aren't going through. I've checked settings and 'Disable Email Communications' is set to 'No'.

Is there anything I could possibly be missing?

Comment: Does your server sending mail ? Check with mail function.

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento use mail() function, some hosting companies have disabled this by default.

You need to check this with your hosting or use email authenticated for notifications, you can try gmail-smtp-app or mageplaza smtp. Both are free.